# Why doesn't git allow 'git reset --hard [path]'

Tags: git, version-control, command-line-interface

When one tries to perform `git reset --hard` with a path specfied, Git does not allow that. In such case user is presented with `fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.` Why is that?

Granted, one can perform `git checkout HEAD -- [path]` which does exactly what I would expect `git reset --hard [path]` to do, but why is it not allowed? Is there any problem with running that due to how things are represented internally? Or is this just a matter of choice by git dev team?

I think this is one of those quirks that make git cli not as clean as it should be and I would really like to know why is that (why not even a message to try checkout instead?). Perhaps my line of thought where `git reset --hard [path]` would equal to `git checkout HEAD -- [path]` is erroneous?

Comment: Ah yeah, quick Google didn't return that result. While the answers there do not really satisfy my curiousity I assume it is just the way it is. Somebody over at the Git dev team thought it would be safer or less confusing. Of course it is neither ;)

Closing the question.